# error in myproxy-logon when seeting up globus toolkit

Tags: globus-toolkit

i am trying to setup globus toolkit. I am following the tutorial "http://toolkit.globus.org/toolkit/docs/5.2/5.2.5/admin/quickstart/#quickstart". When i try to generate a proxy from the myproxy service by using myproxy-logon , as given in the tutorial, i keep getting an error as given below . My hostname is project-OptiPlex-390

```
simplec@project-OptiPlex-390:~$  myproxy-logon -s project-OptiPlex-390
```

Error authenticating: GSS Major Status: Authentication Failed
GSS Minor Status Error Chain:
globus_gss_assist: Error during context initialization
OpenSSL Error: a_verify.c:221: in library: asn1 encoding routines, function ASN1_item_verify: EVP lib
OpenSSL Error: rsa_eay.c:721: in library: rsa routines, function RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT: padding check failed
OpenSSL Error: rsa_pk1.c:100: in library: rsa routines, function RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1: block type is not 01

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because the myproxy-logon must me done from myproxy user. This user is created automatically during the initial globus installation, but it is not listed or accessible automatically. To make it acc'ssible do the following steps
1. nano /etc/passwd

1. Find myproxy in that (usually found in the very end) change **'no-login'** in the line to **'bash'**. and save the file.
2. go to root by su - (the root password must be set beforehand)
3. su - myproxy
4. now you are in the myproxy user. run the myproxy-logon